# Sharing Video on Facebook iOS SDK 4.4

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode6, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-share

In my iOS mobile app, i need to share/upload a video(from Server not a local Video) on Facebook account. I am using iOS 8.0 & FacebookSDK 4.4. I have tried lots of code, but any of them not working.

This is the code what am trying

```
        FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
        video.videoURL = myServerVideoUrl;
        FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
        content.video = video;
        [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:_controller
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:self];
```

but facebook throwing an error like
'Only asset file URLs are allowed for the native dialog"

what am missing..Please help me..Thanks

Please note that,  i need to sent video that are saved n Server.i have videoURl

Thanks

Comment: You can upload /share video from your device only. I mean you can share videos which are there in ImagePickerController.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @hpp in the comment, the video be an [asset URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#videos):

> The video URL videoURL must be an asset URL. You can get a video asset
>   URL e.g. from UIImagePickerController.

If you want to upload a video using an external URL, try video upload [using the Graph API.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads) 
You can upload a video using the edge `/{user_id}/videos` with the `file_url`parameter. Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/#Creating).